# Idle, logout and session expiration, how to make this work with Symfony?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, session-cookies, logout

I am trying to make.. "something" to know if an user is closing the browser or in other case is idle. I need to logout the user using a token.

I am using Symfony2.4 and actual logout include a handler because I need to know if the person is logged in another computer. I can't simple use a session expire because that handler will not execute and the application will still show the user as logged.

I am using this code and works really good!!

```
<script>
        var unloaded = false;
        $(window).on('beforeunload', unload);
        $(window).on('unload', unload);
        function unload(){
            if(!unloaded){
                $('body').css('cursor','wait');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    async: false,
                    url: "{{ logout_url('main') }}",
                    success:function(){
                        unloaded = true;
                        $('body').css('cursor','default');
                    },
                    timeout: 50
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The thing with this is that when the user try to go any link in the website this code execute and they need to log in again.

What can I do to avoid this code run by simply going to another link or what other thing can I do to have similar results?

Answer (score 0):

*This is more of a Javascript question, but well.*

What about wrapping all your external links with javascript that sets a flag that disables your `unload()` function ? This is not very smart to do, though, but should work.

Something like that (not tested) :

```
$('a').click(function(){
    // set the flag
    myFlag = true;
    return true;
}):
```

and in your unload :

```
 function unload(){
   if (myFlag) {
     myFlag = false
     return
  }
  // the rest here
}
```

EDIT :

> If you want to send a request on page unload, it's better to use navigator.sendBeacon() as the data is transmitted asynchronously to the web server when the User Agent has an opportunity to do so, without delaying the unload or affecting the performance of the next navigation. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: I was testing the solution and it works in the case that avoid to logout the user if the anchor points to a local url but I have problems to logout if I close the window because it doesn't have anything to be with the anchor, so, the parameter myFlag doesn't change.

Comment: Is it there another way to know when the user is closing the tap or browser?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem with the external link. What happens exactly ? I've edited the answer to add a precision on how to send a beacon async. It might help.

Comment: I added this to the code:

```
if(!unloaded && myFlag===false){

```

The parameter Myflag change correctly but the code will not run .onunloaded
On the other hand if I change the `&&` by `||` will run every time the page is unloaded even if it is an external link or not.

Any other suggestion?